# Need help related to EXT JS tooltip functionality

Tags: javascript, extjs

We are using `EXTJS 3.1.0`

There is a functionality where we have to add tooltip to an image, using code:

```
function loadToolTip(objImageId,entity_id,entity_type){
    var objImage = document.getElementById(objImageId);
    var tp = new Ext.ToolTip({
        target: objImage,
        autoLoad: {url: ‘some URL’},
        showDelay:500
    });

    var extObjImage = Ext.get(objImageId);
    tp.showAt([extObjImage.getX()+25,extObjImage.getY()+25]);
    if(tp.anchorEl){
        tp.anchorEl.hide();
    }
}
```

This function is called on the `mouseover` event of a image.

It is possible that the user does `mouseover` on the image after changing some data and every time we have to get the tool-tip contents from the server.

The problem we are facing is, it creates multiple tool tips every time we do an mouse over.

Ideally we would want it to be displayed only once. We tried giving id to the tool tip object and then calling `.destroy()` method on that object when `mouseout` event occurs. This also does not work and at times gives JS error.

Answer (score 1):

This or something similar should work for you:

```
function loadToolTip(objImageId,entity_id,entity_type){
  var extObjImage = Ext.get(objImageId);
  var tp = objImage.tp;
  if(!tp)
  {
      var objImage = document.getElementById(objImageId);
      tp = new Ext.ToolTip({
               target: objImage,
               autoLoad: {url: ‘some URL’},
               showDelay:500
      });
      extObjImage.tp = tp;
  }
  tp.showAt([extObjImage.getX()+25,extObjImage.getY()+25]);
  if(tp.anchorEl){
           tp.anchorEl.hide();
  }
```

}